# routing problem with startpage in rails3

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I deleted the Index.html in my /public/ folder. I added a "application" folder in my views.
In it I put a new index.html.erb. This I want to be my startpage/homepage.

In my new "index.html.erb" I set:

`link_to 'sign in', {:controller => 'devise/sessions', :action => 'new'}`

But it redirects me to the "application#index".

I set `root :to => "application#index`

How can I set this to route it to "posts#index" after I sign in, for example?

Is there a chance to use .erb oder .haml in my /public/index.html?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but it sounds like you want users to be directed to a page that is not the root after they log in.  To do this you can implement the after_sign_in_path_for method in your application_controller as [shown in the devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  posts_index_path
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I used `match 'posts' => 'posts#index', :as => 'user_root`. Works fine!